# Entity Framework - How to get filtered Master records along with filtered Detail records?

Tags: entity-framework, master-detail

My class relationship: ClassMaster 1----* ClassSessions
My Goal: Return all ClassMasters that have ClassSessions with StartDateTime greater than the current date, along with these ClassSessions (filtered by date).

In T-SQL I'd do this:

```
select *
   from ClassSession
   join ClassMaster on ClassMaster.ClassId = ClassSession.ClassId
   Where ClassSession.StartDateTime > getdate()
```

I need to realize the same results in an Entity Framework 4 query. This is what I thought it would work, but does not:

```
   var classes = ctx.ClassSessions
                 .Include("ClassMasters")
                 .Where(s => s.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now)
                 .Select(s => s.ClassMaster)
                 .ToList();
```

This give's me all the ClassMasters that have some ClassSession with StartDateTime > current date, but the ClassSessions property comes filled with **all** ClassSessions, including older than current date. I only want ClassSessions with StartDateTime > current date.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var masters = ctx.ClassMasters
         .Where(cm => cm.ClassSessions.Any(cs => cs.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now))
         .Select(cm => new { ClassMaster = cm, ClassSessions = cm.ClassSessions.Where(cs => cs.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now)
         .ToList().Select(e => e.ClassMaster);
```

In case you loaded all ClassSession objects somewhere in context, you can still do this:

```
var masters = ctx.ClassMasters
         .Where(cm => cm.ClassSessions.Any(cs => cs.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now))
         .Select(cm => new ClassMasterWithSessionModel{ ClassMaster = cm, ClassSessions = cm.ClassSessions.Where(cs => cs.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now)
         .ToList();

public class ClassMasterWithSessionModel {
    ClassMaster ClassMaste { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ClassSession> ClassSessions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I still get *all* ClassSession records. I need to get the filtered ones... Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't load anything anywhere else - I've placed your code in an isolated test project with only this query, creating the context at the spot.

Comment: Through SQL Profile, here's what your suggestions translates into:

SELECT ClassMaster.*
FROM ClassMaster
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
             FROM ClassSession
             WHERE ClassSession.ClassID = ClassMaster.ClassID 
               AND ClassSession.StartDateTime >  SysDateTime())

Comment: @Gustavo Cavalcanti: That is not whole SQL code and as you can see, it takes only class masters with sessions.

Comment: Of course, sorry. I was referring to the code you first posted, before you edited it. This works perfectly. Thank you very much.